# azure deployment option source not showing vsts

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

If I select Deployment Option, VSTS as a source is not available. The option was available for the other app service I created using this account. But I come back from lunch and now I can't select VSTS as a source for deployment option. I've tried deleting and re-creating the app service. Logging in on another browser and nothing. If I select the Deployment Center (Preview) option, it DOES see my VSTS repos. So what gives?

[image]

Comment: Only thing I've been able to assume is that since the repo is a VSTS (now called devops I believe), MS wants you to use their systems to deploy. Which is funny b/c I tried it and it was terribly slow and failed randomly (like ever other time it failed after waiting 20-30 minutes). So we switched everything over to github. Works great now.